# Ext Js Grid selModel reset after grid's store updating

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

As above mention in title, I have a grid panel with **selModel** config,
Grid store auto update after 30 seconds, after updating grid store selected record get unselect, that is I don't want.
I want grid records remain selected even after its store get update.
you can see bellow image to understand more.

In this image selected records get unselected when grid store is get update

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, [in my test, the selection is kept](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/243b). Please make a fiddle that exhibits your problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save in additional variable the array of selected records (getSelectionModel().getSelection() -> array of selected records)
2. Reload grid
3. Use getSelectionModel().select(records) to select your "saved" records